# ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am trying to do some DML operation inside a java function. and getting the error.

First i am opening the connection and doing the DML.
then in the same function, i am calling a procedure  which uses the same tables for DML operation. There is commit statement inside the procedure.

I am using the XA oracle datasource so the autocommit is on, i dont need to do the commit in java.

But i am getting ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back. I could not specify the commit option in java as it will give error.

Could anyone help me.

Comment: one more thing i am using IBM websphere server and so using the configured datasource. Is  any configuration needs to be set inside WAS configuration. I tried to run the same code using simple jdbc in java , no error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pragma serially_reusable` at the beginning of your function and procedure, like following :

> **create or replace procedure pr_dml_operation is**
>
> `pragma serially_reusable`;
>        *v_abc_1 number;
>
>         v_def_2 date;*
>     ...
>   **begin**
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> **end**;

By the way, **never** use a ***commit*** statement inside your stored programming block, pricipally. Issue externally. Otherwise, it can corrupt your ***transaction integrity*** for some of your ***dml*** operations.

Comment: one more thing i am using IBM websphere server and so using the configured datasource. Is  any configuration needs to be set inside WAS configuration. I tried to run the same code using simple jdbc in java , no error.

Comment: @Sarbe85 ok, nice. I don't know about IBM Websphere.

Comment: sorry to confuse. i ran my code using JDBC connection without the pragma changes, it ran. This is not running when using WAS data source. Now i am trying to encorporate the changes as mentioned, but getting below error Pragma SERIALLY_REUSABLE must be declared in a package specification

Comment: @Sarbe85 you have to embed the statement `Pragma SERIALLY_REUSABLE` in oracle's `function, procedure body or package's definition&body`, just after their definition.

Comment: Actually there is one pragma autonomous transaction.so didnt change anything. Removed all the commit statements from the procedures as suggested. Thn it worked. Thanks